# Unable to generate assembly code in intel format on OS X

Tags: c, macos

why is this？

```
gcc-8 -masm=intel -m32 -S -fverbose-asm main.c
cc1: error: -masm=intel not supported in this configuration
```

I want to generate intel assembly code for learning。

Comment: Are you on an M1 or M2 system? Have GCC been configured and built with cross-compilation in mind? With Intel target support?

Comment: @Some programmer dude
 intel

Comment: From [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html): "Darwin does not support ‘intel’." "Darwin" is the name of the OS-core of macOS (formerly OSX). You can only get assembly code in the AT&T format.

Comment: How to solve it? Is there no other way?

Comment: Not as I can see. Besides, compiler-generated assembly code is often not the best way to learn assembly, if that's your purpose. Without optimizations it might do some odd steps that's not needed, and optimized assembly code is almost impossible to follow along and read.

Comment: looks like clang will honour -masm=intel on intel cpu macs, but not on an apple silicon. alas, clang also seems to ignore -fverbose-asm.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to generate intel assembly code for learning。

For that I would recommend https://godbolt.org. It will instantly show you the assembly when you stop typing the code.

[image]

Example: https://godbolt.org/z/nbjsTxf95

Comment: You could get the same effect locally by installing a cross-compiler with a Linux x86 target.  But they both have the same side effect that they will use the Linux calling convention and ABI (I forget if there are any differences for x86 but there certainly are for ARM64), and that any inlined library functions will be based on the Linux headers instead of the MacOS ones.

Comment: @NateEldredge godbolt way is way more convenient. You do not need view separate files, build the project etc etc.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I'm just saying, that neither of these actually gives you **a MacOS-targeted compiler** with Intel-syntax output, and that there are cases where the difference could be important.